# How to let IBM watson assistant know which direction you should go to?

Tags: ibm-watson, directions, watson-assistant

I have a watson assistant that serves as a chatbot for the campus. What this chatbot does is that it can give information to where are offices/facilities. It can also give directions. What I cannot implement is the watson assistant must also know how to give directions going up or down a floor, once the user has given the info the bot needs.

An example of how it works:

[image: IBM Assistant]

I'm using slots to get user information from them.

[image: Manage handlers]

How do I let the chatbot know that if the user is below a floor or several floors to the destination it would also include in its reply to go upwards. The same way going down if the user is above a floor from where he/she wants to get to.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to create contextual entities.

1. Create a duplicated Entity of the `@Location_of_offices` and call it from `@From_location_to`.

In the intent `#Directions` on the training questions you mark up the from and two entity. You don't have to mark the explicit value, only the entity.

For example:

[image]

You will need around 10-20 examples of markup. At that point the AI model will understand which entity is which depending how people write their question. You do not need to create an example for every permutation.

There is more details [here with an example](https://sodoherty.ai/2018/07/24/negation-annotation/).

Comment: Is the "annotation" feature also available in the free plan of the service? Because I'm not able to see any annotation features in my interface.

Comment: Are you in the intent you want to edit? With questions in It?

Comment: actually the it's already in the dialog (which in my interface says action) I could just input it from there. It says I'm using the newest Watson assistant user experience. Maybe that's why I can't see the annotation feature?